# Не запускается проект JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

Создал простой проекта(не javaFX) добавил все что нужно, и мне выкидывает исключение, в чем проблема? [image: проект]
[image: Исключение]

Comment: Любой текст здесь принято прикладывать именно текстом, а не скриншотами. У Вас во-первых не влез полезный кусок ошибки на скриншот, а во-вторых для воспроизведения ошибки перепечатывать вручную Ваш код никто не будет!

Answer (score 1):

Судя по второму скриншоту у вас JDK 14. Начиная с 11-версии FX на входит в "базовый состав" JDK. Смените версию JDK на 8 или подключайте библиотеки FX по этому мануалу https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/

Comment: Точно. Спасибо большое